# Java - Could not find or load main class Class01

Tags: java, cmd, path, classpath

Using Java 8

I have set my PATH as 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin'

I also tried to set my CLASSPATH as 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\rt.jar', though I read it is not neccesary.

From *Class01.java* I have no problem creating *Class01.class*

```
javac Class01.java -> created Class01.class
```

Still, when I try to run program

```
java Class01
```

I got message
Error: Could not find or load main class *Class01*

If anyone know, how to fix this, I appreciate every hint.
Btw. My program does nothing but printing Hello world, if it has something to do with my problem.

Comment: Show us the code for your class.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell Java about the **classpath** where it should find your file. I think you are missing the **classpath** parameter in your java command (see below). Here is a simple example how you could create a java file, compile and run it:

### A. Create File:

```
public class X {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Blah!");
    }
}
```

### B. Compile:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac" X.java
```

### C. Run it using the `-classpath` parameter:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -classpath . X
```

This will print out:

```
Blah!
```

Note that JAVA_HOME is a System variable in Windows which needs to point to the location of your Java Runtime Environment.